# Why sometimes a value of "" is not counted as blank in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use the expression =if(cond, A1,"") in cell Z.

Why sometimes when A1 is blank and cond=True I get 0 instead of blank?
Why the cell Z is always counted in counta(), even if it is blank? 
I need blank to be copied and considered as blank. 
The cell is formatted as general but changing this to text doesn't change anything.

Comment: When you ask *'Why **the cell** is always counted in counta(), even if it is blank?*' what cell are you talking about? Do you mean A1 or the cell that the formula is in? btw, `""` is not blank; it is a zero-length-string.

Comment: Have you tried `=if(AND(cond, A1<>""), A1,"").? A truly blank cell has a value of zero and Excel is first and foremost a spreadsheet that is designed to deal with numbers and their values. With no value in a truly blan cell, Excel defaults to a value of zero unless you specifically deal with it as text.

Comment: @Jeeped The cell with the formula. So what will make it blank instead of ""?

Comment: I've tried this and got if(AND) etc. instead of the correct value.

Comment: Nothing will make it truly blank without writing VBA. A formula has to return something and the closest you can get to truly blank is `""` which is a zero-length-string and that is counted by COUNTA. You might try reducing the COUNTA with COUNTBLANK; e.g. `=COUNTA(Z2:Z10)-COUNTBLANK(Z2:Z10)` since COUNTBLANK will count a zero-length-string.

Comment: Thanks, this works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing will make it truly blank without writing VBA. A formula has to return something and the closest you can get to truly blank is "" which is a zero-length-string and that is counted by COUNTA. You might try reducing the COUNTA with COUNTBLANK.

```
=COUNTA(Z2:Z10)-COUNTBLANK(Z2:Z10)
```

Strangely, COUNTBLANK will count a zero-length-string as blank.